# How to combine the database data from two .MDF files I have to instances and I would like to have everything in one instance

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

What would be the easiest way to combine the data from two instances.

I have the following instance names `eftdb.mdf` and `eftusers.mdf`

Comment: Can this help you? [Combine two different SQL server data instance into one db ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ca0d8c17-1d46-4188-a8c4-551a841170ce/how-to-combine-two-different-sql-server-data-instance-into-one-db?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Those seem to be SQL Server database file names, not SQL Server instance names. As far as I know, in SQL Server, "instance" is short for a running SQL Server instance, which can hold multiple databases. On the other hand, a database is stored as a file usually ending in .MDF on a (long-term) storage device.

Comment: Yeah this looks like two datafiles. Why do you think you need them as one file? And why were they created as two files in the first place? There may be a very good reason this was split up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use software like for example RedGate / Apex tools to do a such thing like "database merge" (u can use trails to see if it works for you).
I've already done few merges for my clients using RedGate tools.